# Generate Email Coupon Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

This might be off topic question but I would like to ask it anyway to the developers out there.

Is there a plugin or whatever, that can enable automatic single use coupon code delivery to a user on wordpress/page?

Basically WordPress will send an email to the customer and then the user takes an action (clicks button, clicks link from email), and can see a unique, single use, coupon code back to the wordpress site? Each user of course would see a unique coupon code because there would need to have been a list of unique coupon codes selected/uploaded to begin with.

[image]

Thanks for your kind answers if there is any. Please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for:
[YITH WOOCOMMERCE COUPON EMAIL SYSTEM](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-coupon-email-system/)